# Sumif in R with conditions

Tags: r

I would like to do a conditional sum in R and I have a table such as this below. With this data, I would like to have a forward projection of total value per desk for next 5 days. Value should be included for the date started to the out_date.

```
+-------+------------+-------+-------+------------+------+
| Index |    Date    | Desk  | Value |  Out_date  | Days |
+-------+------------+-------+-------+------------+------+
|    16 | 2020-07-30 | Desk1 | 1     | 2020-08-17 |   12 |
|    51 | 2020-08-13 | Desk2 | 2.000 | 2020-08-14 |    4 |
|    52 | 2020-08-13 | Desk3 | 2.000 | 2020-08-15 |    4 |
|    53 | 2020-08-13 | Desk3 | 2.000 | 2020-08-16 |    4 |
+-------+------------+-------+-------+------------+------+
```

How do I solve this?

How the output should like:

```
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Desk  | 2020-08-14 | 2020-08-15 | 2020-08-16 | 2020-08-17 | 2020-08-18 |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Desk1 |          1 |          1 |      1     |      1     |       0    |
| Desk2 |          2 |          0 |      0     |      0     |       0    |
| Desk3 |          4 |          4 |      2     |      0     |       0    |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean? What should your output look like? Your question is incomlete

Comment: sample output attached.

Comment: So how did you obtain the table? Some of us dont know the terminologies of the other languages.

Comment: sum by date and desk.

Comment: okay, but you talked of forward projection by 5? What does that mean? Also In your date, I only see`2020-07-30` upto `2020-08-13` but in your answer i see  `2020-08-14`

Comment: forward projection for next 5 days. so starting from tommorow. for example, it starts from 2020-07-30 to 2020-08-14, it should be included.

Comment: sorry, but you are still not elaborating. Could you explain how you obtained each value of row 1 in your answer?

Comment: It's not clear why Desk3 has value 0 on 14th August from your description. There are three values for Desk3 on 13th August. These are 2, 2, and 2.5. The days are 4, 4, and 1. How does this predict a 0 on 14th August?

Comment: @AllanCameron, edited the output. it was a sample how it should like.

Comment: simplified the example and added the correct output

Comment: Next time please make the data example *reproducible*.

Comment: Found the Excel user  :-) .   Congrats on starting your journey to software tools that actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it sounds as though each row in your table represents a `Value` associated with a `Desk` for a given period of time. The `Value` associated with that desk starts on a particular `Date`, and continues until the `Out_date`. However, these associations can occur concurrently, which means that on any particular day, a desk may have several associated values. Your intention is to sum these values.

If my understanding is correct, then the following code will get you the relevant sums:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Days = as.numeric(difftime(Out_date, Date, units = "day")) + 1) %>%
  add_row(Index = max(df$Index) + 1, Date = max(df$Date), 
          Desk = "Desk1", Value = 0, Out_date = max(df$Date) + 1, 
          Days = 6) %>%
  mutate(entry = seq(nrow(.)), n = Days) %>% 
  tidyr::uncount(Days) %>%
  group_by(entry) %>%
  mutate(Date_out = seq.Date(min(Date), length.out = max(n), by = "1 day")) %>%
  group_by(Desk, Date_out) %>%
  summarize(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "Date_out", values_from = "Value") %>%
  mutate_if(function(x) any(is.na(x)), function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#>    Desk 2020-07-30 2020-07-31 2020-08-01 2020-08-02 2020-08-03 2020-08-04
#> 1 Desk1          1          1          1          1          1          1
#> 2 Desk2          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 3 Desk3          0          0          0          0          0          0
#>   2020-08-05 2020-08-06 2020-08-07 2020-08-08 2020-08-09 2020-08-10 2020-08-11
#> 1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1
#> 2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 3          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#>   2020-08-12 2020-08-13 2020-08-14 2020-08-15 2020-08-16 2020-08-17 2020-08-18
#> 1          1          1          1          1          1          1          0
#> 2          0          2          2          0          0          0          0
#> 3          0          4          4          4          2          0          0
```

---

**Data from question**

```r
df <- structure(list(Index = c(16L, 51L, 52L, 53L), Date = structure(c(18473, 
18487, 18487, 18487), class = "Date"), Desk = c("Desk1", "Desk2", 
"Desk3", "Desk3"), Value = c(1, 2, 2, 2), Out_date = structure(c(18491, 
18488, 18489, 18490), class = "Date"), Days = c(12L, 4L, 4L, 
4L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you, how to do the forward projection part? for e.g. i need 2020-08-17, 2020-08-18 as part of the dataframe

Comment: @lakesh if none of the Out_date values go past 16th August, how are the predictions to be made?

Comment: the values will be 0 as the desk has no value being used on that day

Comment: @lakesh the data frame will go on as long as there are any values associated with any desks, so you will get a five-day prediction if any desks are active. If there are no desks with any values, then your predictions will be zero. In your new example data frame, the last Out_date was 16th August, so there are no values after this. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: in the new example, the last out_date is 17th August, not 16th August. so beyond 17th August, all desks will be zero.

Comment: @lakesh sorry, that was an off-by-one error. Please see my update, which I think matches your expected output

Comment: but i need 18th August to be part of the dataframe as well.

Comment: @lakesh do you just need a single zero day after the desks have stopped? What are your criteria for when to end the data frame if it is not the last day that any of the desks have value? It's easy to add an empty zero column to the end manually if you want to do that. Is that what you need?

Comment: the criteria is the forward projection of 5 days, need the values for the next 5 days.

Comment: @lakesh five days from when? The last out date?

Comment: the current date

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages have what you need. Use `group_by(Desk, Date)` and `summarize(forecast = your_function)`. Then you can `pivot_wider()` to get your desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Desk, Date) %>%
  summarize(forecast = your_function) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Date", values_from = "forecast")
```

Comment: what is forecast = your_function?

Comment: You want to forecast out five days, but you haven't explained how that works. What forecasting model or formula are you using? That goes where 'your_function` is.

Comment: but i need the value for dates between the start_date to out_date

Answer (score -1):

you can use dplyr and tidyr for this.

```
input <- tibble::tibble(Desk = c("Desk1",
                                 "Desk2",
                                 "Desk1",
                                 "Desk3"), 
                        Date = c("30.07.20", 
                                 "10.08.20",
                                 "10.08.20",
                                 "13.08.20"), 
                        Value = c(0.006,
                                  5.500,
                                  0.300,
                                  2.500))

input %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Desk, Date) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(sum_value = sum(Value)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Date, values_from = sum_value)
```